# Module causing simpleXML error

Tags: magento-1.7, xml, admin-panel, log

After digging around for the cause of a SimpleXMLElement::__construct() error in my logs, I found the culprit to be the module called Mgt_Base.xml in app/etc/modules/. When disabling this module, the errors go away, however I don't know if disabling this module will have any side effects so I'm trying to fix it instead.

I logged out the String it was trying to make the SimpleXMLElement from in Feed.php which got called when visiting the admin panel and it outputted this:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not very familiar with XML, but from what I understand HTML is different than XML. When I tried to make this string into a SimpleXMLElement in a separate test script I got the same errors that appeared in the logs.

Now I'm pretty stuck as to how I can fix this error. I'm not sure if I can just disable this module or if I need to fix something within. Does anybody have any idea?

*Edit: After adding a closing `</hr>` tag in my test script there doesn't seem to be an error. I guess whatever is generating the html is doing a poor job at it. I'll try find the source of whatever is generating it and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXMLElement::__construct()  this type errorin log file comes due to some tag missing or not close properly  in Xml file.

Comment: Right, as said in my edit, there is no closing `</hr>` tag.